# What's a good age to start getting into Mindstorms with my child?

Tags: mindstorms

What is a good age to start getting a child into LEGO Mindstorms? Also, how would you recommend introducing her?

I can't wait to start building robots with my daughter. She loves LEGO and the idea of robots, and I know she will have a blast. I know I will need to (and actually really want to) help her do everything.

I think I already know the answer (aka, now as she's almost 5), but I'm looking to see what suggestions others might have from their own experiences. Thanks!

Comment: My kid is 3. I think I'm... er he's at the right age.

Answer (score 4):

I started at age 9 and it was just right for me. Since Mindstorms now comes with a modified version of LabVIEW, I'd maybe wait until they can learn how to use the software.

Comment: I say there's no hard and fast number, just "when she's ready", and I have faith that you will know that better than anyone else, Chris.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a lot of variability in terms of what can be considered an appropriate age for a child to begin Mindstorm.  For any given age, it is important that you scale the difficulty of any given activity to the child's knowledge, skills, and attention.  Indeed, part of the learning process is providing a challenge, but with children essential they feel successful.  As adults, we tend to focus on outcomes -- that is, the build in the final form. With children, give most of your attention to the process.  That is how you will ultimately rope them in to become master builders.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In order to have fun with Mindstorms you need to have a decent knowledge of maths and some physics ... but it is also a great incentive to learn these... I would say 9-11 does best. But it really depends of your child.